# test onclick in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Quick question**: How do i check if a submit button is clicked in a function.

**explained question**:
ok, so I have a validate script for my sign-up page. The validate function is run onblur of every input (after the submit button has been clicked first).

However, the validate script not only gives the inputs a red background if the correct information hasn't been entered, but it also displays an alert message.

My problem is: I only want to display the alert message if the submit button is clicked, otherwise i just want to do change the background color. So how do I check if a submit buttons is clicked, in a function. 
I could just have two different functions, one to be run for all the inputs. and one to be run for the submit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register the submit event to your form to validate before it is submitted.

Added: You should register the function in document ready event.

```
$(function(){
    $("#myformid").submit(function()
     { if(!highlightNshowError())//your function to validate the form, return false if validation failed
           return false; //stop submitting the form
       else
           return true;
     });
});
```

or simply

```
$(function(){
    $("#myformid").submit(function()
     { 
         return highlightNshowError();
     });
});
```

Comment: It depends on what is returned from highlightNshowError()     edited: alright I got the point, the login in the two pieces of code seems confusing, I will edit it.

Comment: wait, Ive encountered a problem. Every-time I run the validate script with the $("#myformid").submit the alert box appears once. then if i click the submit button again, it appears twice in a row. then if i click the submit button again the alert appears 3 times in a row etc etc.

Comment: @dgmama post your code for highlistNshowError , there might be bug there , we can fix that , post the code.

Comment: well mines like this:                                         $("#ContactForm").submit(function() { 
  if(error.length > 0){
     alert(error);
  return false;
} else return true; 

 });

Comment: what is error ?? do you have any loop which loops through all text boxes?

Comment: @dgamma3 I guess you directly called the function I provided. You should register it once only in the document ready event and it will be triggered automatically. Read the original answer I have just edited.